# geom_bar of z-standardized values with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, facet-wrap

I am creating a barplot based on z-standardized values for students who belong to different classes. As values are z-standardized I would want the bars to start at zero. However, if some students have positive values for a specific variable and others have negative values, the bar extends in both directions (pos & neg).

Example:

```
new_tibble <- tibble(Class = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                     var_name = c("a", "b", "a", "b", 
                                  "c", "d", "c", "d"), 
                     var_value = c(-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 2, 2))
new_tibble %>%  
   ggplot(aes(x = var_name, y = var_value)) + 
   geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), stat = "identity")  +
   facet_wrap(~ factor(Class), ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update following OP comment:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

new_tibble %>%
  group_by(Class, var_name) %>% 
  summarise(var_value = sum(var_value), .groups = "drop")%>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = var_name, y = var_value)) + 
  geom_col()  +
  facet_wrap( ~factor(Class), ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = -1:1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to distinguish between positive and negative values. Do you have any suggestions for keeping the values the way they are but changing the way they are plotted?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you so  much for your new answer. I didn't put it clearly. I would want and expect the positive and negative values to be averaged. I would want the plot to be positive a +1 (being the mean of 2 and -1).

Comment: What would you expect to see in the case of class 1 where the values are -1? would you expect to see a bar chart from 0 to -1?

Comment: Do you mean the sum rather than the mean (or average). The sum of 2 and -1 = 1, whereas the mean of 2 and - 1 = (2 + - 1)/2  = 1/2 = 0.5.

Comment: Yes, I would expect ggplot to behave in a similar way as it does with non-standardized values. Bars should always start at zero and only reach in one direction - being either positive or negative. To answer your question: "in the case of class 1 where the values are -1? would you expect to see a bar chart from 0 to -1?" yes.

Comment: Does the revised output answer the question?